# rename files with a shift in numbers

Tags: batch-rename

I want to rename a bunch of files which are called IMG0189.jpeg IMG0190.jpeg etc to something like IMG01.jpeg IMG02.jpeg etc respectively. Are there any way doing this using rename command? Or anything else? I tried reading the manual but it's very brief and doesn't give any idea about shifting numbers.

Comment: Also covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/880467/1270008) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch rename with id shifting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251258/batch-rename-with-id-shifting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
ls > /tmp/list ; seq -w `ls | wc -l` | paste /tmp/list - | awk -F\\t '{ print $1, "IMG"$2".jpeg"}' | xargs -n2 mv
```

- List the files and redirect the list to a temporary file `/tmp/list`
- Write a `seq`uence of numbers, padded with zeros, equal to the number of files to STDOUT

  - The file count is gotten by listing the files and piping to the `wc` (word count) app in "lines" mode
- `paste` the sequence of numbers from the previous command onto the right side of the list of files from `/tmp/list`

  - Paste sticks two files together as columns separated by a `TAB` character
  - Pipe the output to the next program
- Use a small `awk` program to reformat these two fields

  - Separators specified as tab (`\t` - the first slash is to escape the second one)
  - First field `$1`, the original file name printed as-is
  - Second field `$2`, the sequence number, printed with an IMG prefix and a .jpeg suffix
  - Pipe the output to the next program
- Using `xargs`, pass the pairs of arguments to the `mv` (move / rename command)

  - `-n2` means that it will pass 2 of them at a time

NB, this presumes that your original file names do not contain spaces.

If you want to start at a number other than 1, you need to manipulate the parameters of seq ; e.g.

```
COUNT=`ls | wc -l` ; FIRST=32 ; LAST=$(($FIRST + $COUNT)) ; seq -w $FIRST $LAST
```

Comment: Awesome, that exactly does what I want. And thanks so much for the great explanation. Is there any way that I can tell it to start numbering with for example 01 and then get to 10,11 etc? Also, I would like to know if I can start the numbering from an arbitrary number, for example from 32!

Comment: The "-w" parameter on `seq` makes it automatically pad to the required number of zeroes to hold the sequence you asked for, so that's already covered. See edit for starting at different number.