# batch rename with id shifting?

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I need to batch rename bunch of files with id in name, adding a constant number to id

```
 <id>-xxx.txt => <id+shift>-yyy.txt
```

Any ideas how to make it? Some awk maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
constant=42
for f in *.txt; do    # choose your pattern as appropriate.
    IFS='-.' read id suffix ext <<< "$f"
    newname="$(( 10#$id + constant ))-yyy.$ext"
    echo mv "$f" "$newname"
done
```

I added "10#" in the arithmetic expression to ensure the number is treated as base-10 even if it begins with a zero.

If this doesn't meet your needs, please provide more requirements in the question.

Comment: it's quite good, only problem is that 'xxx' part is variable, so i need to extract id and that part separately, modify id and merge again

Comment: Does 'xxx' contain dashes or dots? If not, then this code will work: the `suffix` variable will contain whatever 'xxx' is. If there can be dashes and dots, I can provide alternatives, but this is exactly the kind of information you need to provide in the question.

Comment: ok, I figured this out (IFS was quite new for me) and I made it working. Thanks a lot